# Discord Bot DM Questionnaire discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm basically trying to make an application/questionnaire discord bot. When triggered, the bot is supposed to notify the user via dm and asks if user wants to proceed. User replies with "proceed" and bot starts with the first question and wait for a response from user. Bot then takes response and store it and proceeds with the next question and it loops until it finishes the last question. I'm stuck at the part where the bot sends the first question and I get no response when I answer. Any help would be appreciated.

PS. I'm fairly new to python and discord py

```
@bot.command()
async def apply(ctx):
    Name = ''
    Age = ''
    user = ctx.author
    name = ctx.author.display_name
    q = ['What is your full real name?',
                 'What is your age?']
    i = 0
#embed
    message = 'Thank you ' + name + \
    ' for taking interest in Narcos City Police Department. You will be asked a series of question which you are required to answer to the fullest of your ability.   Please reply with *proceed* to start your application.'
    embedmsg =discord.Embed(title = 'NARCOS CITY POLICE DEPARTMENT', color = Police)
    embedmsg.set_thumbnail(url = thumbnail)
    embedmsg.add_field(name = 'Human Resources:', value = message)

#initial bot response
    dmchannel = await ctx.author.send(embed=embedmsg)

#check
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.author.dm_channel
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if msg.content == 'proceed':
            async def askq(q):
                await ctx.author.send(q)
                msg
                return msg.content
            Name = await askq(q[0])
            Age = await askq(q[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check function is a bit messed up. You can try the following:

```py
    @bot.command
    async def apply(ctx):
        await ctx.author.send("Filler") # Sends a message to the author

        questions = ["", "", ""] # Create your list of answers

        answers = [] # Empty list as the user will input the answers

        def check(m):
            return ctx.author == m.author and isinstance(m.channel, discord.DMChannel) # Check that the messages were sent in DM by the right author

        for i in questions:
            await ctx.author.send(i) # Sends the questions one after another
            try:
                msg = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=XXX, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.author.send("Timeout message.")
                return # Will no longer proceed, user has to run the command again
            else:
                answers.append(msg) # Appends the answers, proceed

        [OPTIONAL PART]
        channel = bot.get_channel(ChannelID)
        e = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color)
        e.title = "New application"
        e.description = f"First answer: {answers[0].content} [...]"
        await channel.send(embed=e)
```

***What did I do in the code?***

- Built in a different check to make sure the answers were sent in a DM channel by the author of the command
- Put the answers into a list (`answers.append(msg)`)
- Sent the answers in an embed to a channel of your choice

**!! Note that with this method the bot will directly start to ask your questions !!**

If you want to first ask if the user wants to start with the questions you can build in something like:

```py
            try:
                preply = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=43200)
                while preply.content != "proceed": # If answer is not "proceed"
                    await ctx.author.send("If you want to proceed please run the command again and type `proceed`")
                    preply = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=XXX)
                await ctx.author.send("We will now proceed.") # If answer is "proceed"
                [Rest of the code above in the right indentation.)
```

Comment: dude! can I message you anywhere? I'm really stuck on this one T_T

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: I just saw your input and I'm trying to implement it on the bot now. Can I remove the time out?

Comment: Yes, I just set it to `XXX` as you may want to set your own value.

Comment: does setting it to 0 means it doesn't time out?

Comment: If you do not add `timeout` there will be no timeout

Comment: where do you insert the proceed question?>

Comment: I added it at the end if you want to build that in.

Comment: like where in the code do you insert it at? when does the try start at

Comment: After the check obviously.